# Android Studio on M1 MacBook Pro Cannot Simulate System Images with ABI armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, android-studio, arm, android-virtual-device, apple-m1

Android Studio on my M1 Macbook Pro can simulate all the system images with ABI arm64-v8a really well (API 24, 29, 30, 31). However, it fails to run all the images with ABI armeabi-v7a (e.g. API 19 KitKat). The error message is "AVD Manager: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_19 has terminated".

I'm not sure why the older images only have ABI armeabi-v7a. I wonder if there is a workaround for this or I need to wait for Android Studio to patch it.

Here is a screenshot of the available images for reference

[image: [Here is a screenshot of the available images for reference]]

Comment: Known issue since Android Emulator M1 Preview: https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview `32 bit ARM apps won't work`

Comment: I cannot run even 24 and 25 for unknown reason ? Are there somewhere builds that run ? I am using 29, 30 , 31 but I need also to test Android 8 and 7 .

Answer (score 1):

Apple M1 doesn't have `aarch32` mode, the on-chip hardware 32bit emulator.

And I doubt anyone would write an `aarch32` software emulator for `aarch64` since the hardware emulator is a proven, powerful, and cheap option for chip vendors.

It's not a "known issue" since it will never be resolved IMO.

Comment: It is now 2024, is there still no way to run 32 bit Android apps on Apple Silicon?