# Is there Android 4.4 KitKat with arm64-v8a?

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1, arm64, apple-silicon

My goal is to emulate virtual device with Android 4.4 arm64-v8a on Mac Mini M1.

The problem:

1. Android Studio does not provide Android 4.4 with arm64-v8a.
2. armeabi-v7a does not work with Apple Slicion.

What I've done:

1. I tried to emulate the device with armeabi-v7a, but it throws `The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_APi_19 has terminated`. [Reference: there is no software emulator for armeabi-v7a yet for aarch64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083758/android-studio-on-m1-macbook-pro-cannot-simulate-system-images-with-abi-armeabi)

Is there an alternative? Perhaps running Android Kitkat with System Image x86?

Answer (score 0):

armeabi-v7a will not work as it is 32-bit. On M1 there is no possibility to run 32bit apps / emulators natively, however you can try:

1. Installing windows / macOS which is 32-bit compatible through Parallels
2. Check CrossOver - people play 32bit games via CrossOver [link1](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/crossover-allows-x86-windows-apps-to-run-on-apple-m1-macs.2269730/) [link2](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/this-is-huuge-32bit-windows-apps-on-m1-macs-spoiler-even-witcher-3.2269689/)

I would recommend to install Parallels, but still running armeabi-v7a could be a tedious task.

Comment: Installing windows will not be an option. I installed Xcode, Android Studio (with 2 system image / emulator), IntelliJ IDEA, VS Code, and Docker (without any image) and the remaining storage is 158 GB. Anyway, as I read, I found that Android Studio will not support API 23 and below for arm64-v8a. I will see what I can do since some hardware still use Android 4.4 for the field personnel.

Comment: According to storage requirements https://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/resources/ you need 16GB for win10 so I believe 25 - 30 GB would be enough. Still, I think your only option would be getting a physical device with KitKat.